# "callback is not a function" with $bindToContext

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

In my angular-meteor app I'm using mdg:camera. I'm trying to update a field from the callback to show the image. Here's the code snippet:

```
this.addImageToPost = () => {
    MeteorCamera.getPicture({
        quality: 50
    }, this.$bindToContext((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        this.imgDataUrl = data;
    }));
};
```

This has been working great. But now after I finished updating my app to use meteor 1.3 (with all the new updates to angular package and mdg:camera as well) this became broken with a "callback is not a function" error.

If I remove the "this.$bindToContext" part, I get a working code - only obviously it's not reactive.

Any idea what's going on? I wonder if the newest updates broke something...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!